# GWT app UI wont display

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I have implemented a simple GWT app that uses 1 Place and 1 Activity (which I have implemented as a Presenter which extends an `AbstractActivity` and which contains a `Composite` "view" subclass). The 1 and only UI object in the view is a [GWT-Bootstrap NavBar](http://gwtbootstrap.github.com/gwt-bootstrap/apidocs/index.html) that I want presented at the very top of my "home page".

I'm running the app locally from inside Eclipse and am not getting any compiler or runtime errors. When I go to the URL that the **Development Mode** console points me to, I get a slight pause in the browser (I assume this is the browser "downloading" the JavaScript) and then I see a blank white screen (instead of my NavBar). The window title is correct (I set this in the module's HTML page) and when I view source I see the same HTML source, so I know that the app's JavaScript is getting to the browser properly. It's just not rendering the NavBar.

I have sprinkled `System.out.println()` statements throughout `onModuleLoad()`, my default `ActivityManager`, `ActivityMapper`, `PlaceHistoryMapper`, presenter and view `Composite`, and all these `sysout` statements print in the dev console; telling me that I have wired everything together correctly, and that at runtime when the `PlaceHistoryHandler#handleCurrentHistory` method is called (from inside `onModuleLoad`), I should be seeing my NavBar.

The only possibilities I can think of are:

1. I have configured `gwt-bootstrap` incorrectly; or
2. I'm not using UiBinder correctly
3. Something else is wrong with how I am using Activities and Places, or perhaps how I am attaching the UI to `RootLayoutPanel` inside `onModuleLoad()`.

As for `gwt-bootstrap`:

- I placed the JAR on my project's classpath (I know this because when I include a new `UiField` of type `NavBar` inside my widget/view, I don't get any compiler errors)
- I added `<inherits name="com.github.gwtbootstrap.Bootstrap"/>` to my GWT module XML

So if there's anything else I have to configure, please let me know!

As for the UiBinder stuff, here's my widget/view:

```
public class WebRootDisplay extends BaseDisplay {

    private static WebRootDisplayUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(WebRootDisplayUiBinder.class);

    interface WebRootDisplayUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, WebRootDisplay> {
    }

    @UiField
    Navbar navBar;

    public WebRootDisplay(EventBus eventBus) {
        super(eventBus);

        System.out.println("I get this printing to the console at runtime.");

        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

        System.out.println("...and this too!");
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
    xmlns:b="urn:import:com.github.gwtbootstrap.client.ui">
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <b:Navbar ui:field="navBar">
            <b:Nav>
                <b:NavLink href="http://www.google.com">
                    Home
                </b:NavLink>
            </b:Nav>
        </b:Navbar>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

One thing I noticed is that I've got my `NavBar` inside an `HTMLPanel` in the UiBinder XML. I did this because I used the Google-Eclipse plugin to generate a new UiBinder for me (which autogenerated both the `Composite` (which I then modified to extend `BaseDisplay`, which itself extends `Composite`) as well as the UiBinder snippet. I figured GWT wants me to put all the UI fields inside this `HTMLPanel`...(?)

If I'm missing anything here please let me know. I'm not instantiating the `NavBar` field because I *believe* that's what `createAndBindUi` does for me.

If both my `gwt-bootstrap` config and my use of UiBinder looks correct, then something else is obviously wrong and I will have to post more code. I just wanted to hold off on that initially before these first two items were ruled out. Thanks in advance!

#### Update

Here is `onModuleLoad`:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Some homegrown DI stuff. I have verified that the injector works properly.
    ApplicationScope appScope = new ApplicationScope();

    setInjector(new ApplicationInjector(appScope,
        InjectorProvider.newMasterProvider()));

    // Add the sole composite child to the RootLayoutPanel.
    // I have verified that injectWebRootDisplay returns a fully configured
    // WebRootDisplay instance.
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(injector.injectWebRootDisplay());

    historyHandler.register(placeController, eventBus, defaultPlace);
    historyHandler.handleCurrentHistory();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste the `onModuleLoad()` part of your code please?

If you don't got any `Exception` and error message, I think you should check that you add the view properly to the `RootPanel`, or when you run the app you should check that the `view` is there in a `div` in the `HTML` and just unvisible or something similar.

The `UiBinder` part looks fine in a first look.

**EDIT:**
This `onModuleLoad()` doesn't said too much to me, but you could try something.
I always use the RootLayoutPanel.get() method in the following way:

```
RootLayoutPanel.get("someDivId").add(injector.injectWebRootDisplay());
```

So I always add a `div` or `table` to the placeholder `HTML` with a `id`, so you can refer to that div when you get the RootPanel. I'm not confident about this is necessary, but I saw this at the first time, and it's working properly.
If you have question or problem, please let me know. :)

Comment: Thanks @Endox (+1) - please see my update at the bottom of my original question. Thanks again!

Comment: I think you have mistaken RootLayoutPanel for RootPanel. RootLayoutPanel doesn't allow you to choose element where to place it. It doesn't even have a `get(String param)` method=)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've tried a local example looking exactly like yours code, and I think that problem is not in UI binder. The code you provided so far, is correct, so it most likely that the error is somewhere else.

The biggest suspect is the `BaseDisplay` class. As far as I can see, this class is not from GWT or gwt-bootstrap. You can really quickly check it, by changing `WebRootDisplay` class, so it extends classic GWT `Composite` class instead of `BaseDisplay` (and disabling all mvp stuff for while). If it works, you have a proof that the problem is caused by 'BaseDisplay'

Since I don't have the full code, I can only assume that `WebRootDisplay` is used also for displaying the views, and most likely the error is that when view is added to that class, previously added widget (in your case it is a NavBar which you add in constructor of `WebRootDisplay`) is removed. Most likely the problem should be in methods `setWidget` and `initWidget`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with GWT Activities and Places, a common culprit of a blank white page is failing to register the Place's Tokenizer with the PlaceHistoryMapper as so:

```
/**
 * PlaceHistoryMapper interface is used to attach all places which the
 * PlaceHistoryHandler should be aware of. This is done via the @WithTokenizers
 * annotation or by extending PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory and creating a
 * separate TokenizerFactory.
 */
@WithTokenizers({
    MyPlace.Tokenizer.class,
    SomeOtherPlace.Tokenizer.class})
public interface AppPlaceHistoryMapper extends PlaceHistoryMapper {}
```

See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces#PlaceHistoryMapper

Another cause for a white page (particularly when using RootLayoutPanel.get() with a single place is failing to map the place correctly in the ActivityMapper:

```
/**
 * AppActivityMapper associates each Place with its corresponding
 * {@link Activity}
 * 
 * @param clientFactory
 *            Factory to be passed to activities
 */
public class AppActivityMapper implements ActivityMapper {
    private ClientFactory clientFactory;

    public AppActivityMapper(ClientFactory clientFactory) {
        super();
        this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public Activity getActivity(Place place) {
        if (place instanceof MyPlace)
            return new MyActivity((MyPlace) place, clientFactory);
        else if (place instanceof SomeOtherPlace)
            return new SomeOtherActivity((SomeOtherPlace) place, clientFactory);

        return null; // If your return null with single place bound to RootLayoutPanel
        // you may get a blank white page
    }
}
```

See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces#ActivityMapper

Without a more complete code sample it is impossible to determine exactly what is happening, but the two causes outlined above are common oversights which may help anyone who comes across this thread.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of System.println use GWT.log messages.  Then open the Javascript console (of Firebug or Chrome) and see where your code ends up. GWT.log will print out in the browser console, so you can see what the compiled JS code does.

Also, if you compile with the Pretty mode, you'll see the generated Javascript code in the browser and be able to step through and see what is being called (or not).

Comment: It doesn't work for him in *Development mode*. How compiling the whole thing supposed to help?

Comment: compiling GWT code and stepping through it can sometimes show you where code either crashes or fails to call your code.